# MySQL Workbench fails to store password in vault

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to access my SQL server through MySQL Workbench. So I click the + sign to create a new connection.

At this point I choose a connection name and enter the hostname, username, and port. Then I click "Store in Vault" to store my password.

So I then enter my password to store.

[image: Password entry]

At this point I click "Test Connection", but despite having just stored my password in the vault, I am yet again prompted again to enter my password.

I comply and enter my password once more. This time I get a connection failure message:

[image: Connection Failure]

I know that my username, password, hostname, and port are all correct.

I just wanted to know if the fact that MySQL seemingly 'forgets' that I stored my password in the vault is indicative of any particular errors on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final error message shows the real problem. Your credentials are not correct or the user is not allow to connect. Hence MySQL Workbench asks again for them when you test the connection (as it failed to connect using your stored credentials).